# Should aws-sdk (for Javascript) work on deno?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm trying the following:

```
import { config } from "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts";
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        AccessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        SecretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    }
})

async function list() {
s3/interfaces/listobjectsv2commandinput.html
    const objs = await client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket'
    }))

    console.log(objs)
}

list()
```

and receiving the following error:

```js
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
    return data.byteLength === 0;
                ^
    at isEmptyData (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@aws-crypto/sha256-js@v1.1.0-dHYF8d6vKNrHMAy8OSBp/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/@aws-crypto/sha256-js.js:273:17)
    at Sha2563.update (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@aws-crypto/sha256-js@v1.1.0-dHYF8d6vKNrHMAy8OSBp/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/@aws-crypto/sha256-js.js:227:11)
    at Sha2563.update (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@aws-crypto/sha256-browser@v1.1.0-zAkPQPOfexzoM9OQsM4x/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/@aws-crypto/sha256-browser.js:223:17)
    at hmac (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@aws-sdk/signature-v4@v3.18.0-HsTZ7xRuxTwnMM5vqyYs/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/@aws-sdk/signature-v4.js:113:8)
    at https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@aws-sdk/signature-v4@v3.18.0-HsTZ7xRuxTwnMM5vqyYs/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/@aws-sdk/signature-v4.js:56:22
    at step (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/tslib@v2.2.0-aACEbPrqb1U8uyinA6J0/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/tslib.js:221:23)
    at Object.next (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/tslib@v2.2.0-aACEbPrqb1U8uyinA6J0/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/tslib.js:168:18)
    at https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/tslib@v2.2.0-aACEbPrqb1U8uyinA6J0/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/tslib.js:154:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter2 (https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/tslib@v2.2.0-aACEbPrqb1U8uyinA6J0/dist=es2020,mode=imports/optimized/tslib.js:136:14)
```

I'm just wondering whether someone with more experience might recognize this as something I've not done properly or already knows this is an issue with running on Deno.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply camel casing those props worked:

```
const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    }
})
```